# JS regex check agains everything but https

Tags: javascript, regex

I a working in a specific project that has a regex guideline that checks for the opposite of what I am used to. Usually I would match the string to see if it has what I am expecting and then pass. But this project is built the opposite.

The regex will pass if the given string does not contain what I specify. So I have this as my test:

```
^((?!(http:|^www))(?!\\s).)+$
```

Basically if the url does not look like this `www.somewebsite.com` or this `http://...` then it passes. So if `https://...` is given it passes. However I need to have this also not allow `somewebsite.com` for the instance a user inputs the url without http, or www. What else can be added to this check so only https gets through?

Sorry my regex is not good

EDIT:
I provide a config object to a config builder and it renders inputs on the page. In the config object is where I set a regex validation string to test with. So past providing this I cant do anything else without overriding with extra JS (and this is not an option either)

Comment: i would parse and normalize the url before using the regexp using an A tag's href property.

Comment: Please provide a list of (more) sample inputs. Enough different matching and different non-matching so that if a solution has the same matches it is almost sure to satisfy you.

Comment: @dandavis I wish I could do anything to this. I provide a config object to a config builder and it renders inputs on the page. In the config object is where I set a regex validation string to test with. So past providing this I cant do anything else without overriding with extra JS, and this most likely would give a rejected pull request.

Comment: This question is not quite clear. If you mean you need to match a string that does not start with `http:` or `www.`, use `^(?!http:|www\.).*`. If you need to only allow strings that start with `https:`, use `^https:.*`.